# Populate values with subquery from same query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Hopefully I'm explaining this correctly.

Have a query where I'm joining a few tables.  The way the system is setup, when one column is populated, the other is blank, and vice versa.  Here's kind of what my query results look like currently:

```
    CREATE TABLE mytable(
   mainID INTEGER  NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY 
  ,acctID VARCHAR(4) NOT NULL
  ,emailID INTEGER  NOT NULL
  ,type INTEGER  NOT NULL
  ,created DATE  NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO mytable(mainID,acctID,emailID,type,created) VALUES (ABC123,'1/1/2018',12345,NULL,'12345');
INSERT INTO mytable(mainID,acctID,emailID,type,created) VALUES (ABC124,'1/1/2018',12345,NULL,'12345');
INSERT INTO mytable(mainID,acctID,emailID,type,created) VALUES (ABC125,'1/1/2018',12345,NULL,'12345');
INSERT INTO mytable(mainID,acctID,emailID,type,created) VALUES (ABC126,'1/1/2018',12345,NULL,'12345');
INSERT INTO mytable(mainID,acctID,emailID,type,created) VALUES (ABC127,'1/1/2018',12345,NULL,'12345');
INSERT INTO mytable(mainID,acctID,emailID,type,created) VALUES (ABC127,'1/1/2018',12345,NULL,'12345');
INSERT INTO mytable(mainID,acctID,emailID,type,created) VALUES (ACB234,'1/2/2018',NULL,ABCDEFG,NULL);
INSERT INTO mytable(mainID,acctID,emailID,type,created) VALUES (ACB234,'1/2/2018',NULL,ABCDEFG,NULL);
INSERT INTO mytable(mainID,acctID,emailID,type,created) VALUES (ACB234,'1/2/2018',NULL,ABCDEFG,NULL);
INSERT INTO mytable(mainID,acctID,emailID,type,created) VALUES (ACB234,'1/2/2018',NULL,ABCDEFG,NULL);
INSERT INTO mytable(mainID,acctID,emailID,type,created) VALUES (ACB234,'1/2/2018',NULL,ABCDEFG,NULL);
INSERT INTO mytable(mainID,acctID,emailID,type,created) VALUES (ACB234,'1/2/2018',NULL,ABCDEFG,NULL);
INSERT INTO mytable(mainID,acctID,emailID,type,created) VALUES (ABC567,'1/3/2018',789432,NULL,'789432');
INSERT INTO mytable(mainID,acctID,emailID,type,created) VALUES (ABC567,'1/3/2018',789432,NULL,'789432');
INSERT INTO mytable(mainID,acctID,emailID,type,created) VALUES (ABC567,'1/3/2018',789432,NULL,'789432');
INSERT INTO mytable(mainID,acctID,emailID,type,created) VALUES (ABC567,'1/3/2018',789432,NULL,'789432');
INSERT INTO mytable(mainID,acctID,emailID,type,created) VALUES (ABC567,'1/3/2018',789432,NULL,'789432');
INSERT INTO mytable(mainID,acctID,emailID,type,created) VALUES (ABC567,'1/3/2018',789432,NULL,'789432');
INSERT INTO mytable(mainID,acctID,emailID,type,created) VALUES (ABC980,'1/4/2018',NULL,QRXS,NULL);
INSERT INTO mytable(mainID,acctID,emailID,type,created) VALUES (ABC980,'1/4/2018',NULL,QRXS,NULL);
INSERT INTO mytable(mainID,acctID,emailID,type,created) VALUES (ABC980,'1/4/2018',NULL,QRXS,NULL);
```

Here's what I'm trying to make it look like:

```
id  date    pid pcid    lid
ABC123  1/1/2018    12345   XYZ 12345
ABC124  1/1/2018    12345   XYZ 12345
ABC125  1/1/2018    12345   XYZ 12345
ABC126  1/1/2018    12345   XYZ 12345
ABC127  1/1/2018    12345   XYZ 12345
ABC127  1/1/2018    12345   XYZ 12345
ACB234  1/2/2018    98765   ABCDEFG 98765
ACB234  1/2/2018    98765   ABCDEFG 98765
ACB234  1/2/2018    98765   ABCDEFG 98765
ACB234  1/2/2018    98765   ABCDEFG 98765
ACB234  1/2/2018    98765   ABCDEFG 98765
ACB234  1/2/2018    98765   ABCDEFG 98765
ABC567  1/3/2018    789432  ZF1 789432
ABC567  1/3/2018    789432  ZF2 789432
ABC567  1/3/2018    789432  ZF3 789432
ABC567  1/3/2018    789432  ZF4 789432
ABC567  1/3/2018    789432  ZF5 789432
ABC567  1/3/2018    789432  ZF6 789432
ABC980  1/4/2018    8675309 QRXS    8675309
ABC980  1/4/2018    8675309 QRXS    8675309
ABC980  1/4/2018    8675309 QRXS    8675309
```

Here's roughly what I was attempting:  I feel like I'm overlooking something very obvious however and making this more difficult than it has to be...

```
 SELECT    a.id
           a.date
           b.pid
           b.pcid
           c.lid
    FROM table a
         LEFT JOIN table b
            on a.id = b.id(not bringing this column in)
         LEFT JOIN table c
            on b.pid = c.lid
         WHERE b.pcid IN ( SELECT lid from table c
                          WHERE b.id = c.id)
```

Basically, I'm trying to populate the missing columns from PID, PCID, LID.  When PCID exists.  In table, B, there are 3 Ids.  If pcid is populated then pid isn't, etc.  I want to populate both pid and pcid.

Answer (score 0):

Your first problem is you're telling SQL that columns can't be NULL, yet you're populating the rows with NULL values.
In your CREATE TABLE table, those last 3 columns shouldn't say NOT NULL if you need them to hold NULL values.

Your second problem is you haven't made it clear in your question where you are getting the values 'XYZ' from, or any of the other NULL values which, in your expected output you seem to be populating with values out of nowhere.  Where did those values come from?
It makes it hard to answer when the question doesn't include all clues.

Answer (score 0):

In the interest of time, I just dropped the columns I needed into another table, and updated from there.